# C++ init class members constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` contains an instance of `Foo`, which needs to be initialized whit some data in a file. An initializer list should not be ok, because at the time of the initialization the computer doesn't already know what value assign to `Foo`.

```
class Foo {
        int x;
    public:
        Foo(int new_x) : x(new_x) {}
};

class Bar {
        Foo FooInstance;
    public:
        Bar(const char * fileneme)
        /* Auto calls FooInstance() constructor, which does not exist
           Shoild I declare it to only avoid this error? */
        {
            /* [...] reading some data from the file */
            // Init a new FooInstance calling FooInstance(int)
            FooInstance = Foo(arg);
            /* Continue reading the file [...] */
        }
};
```

It would be a good choice to create a new object, initializing it, then copying it in `FooInstance` as shown in the source?
Or maybe declaring `FooInstance` as raw pointer, then init it with new? (and destroy it in `Bar` destructor)
What is the most elegant way to initialize `FooInstance`?

Comment: I'd either have `FooInstance` be able to take a default-constructor with an `Initialization()` class method that can be called in the Bar constructor, or make it a pointer and create it with `new` and the appropriate data in the Bar constructor. Creating it outside and copying it in is generally hard to follow and sloppy, though obviously there are exceptions to all rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use delegating constructors (since C++11) and extra function:

```
MyDataFromFile ReadFile(const char* filename);

class Bar {
        Foo FooInstance;
    public:
        Bar(const char* fileneme) : Bar(ReadFile(filename))  {}

    private:
        Bar(const MyDataFromFile& data) : FooInstance(data.ForFoo)
        {
            // other stuff with MyDataFromFile.
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If the necessary argument can be computed, then you can use a helper function:

```
class Bar
{
    static int ComputeFooArg() { /* ... */ };

public:
    Bar(const char * filename) : FooInstance(ComputeFooArg())
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```